# Incorrect appearance in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I'm getting incorrect look in internet explorer 7,6, etc. It started when I added `float: right;` to `#social-share` div tag. I tried setting `display: inline-block;` to it and `clear: both;` but nothing worked for me.

You can [see the issue live](http://freshbeer.lv/new/latvian/index.php). Here is my code:

#### HTML

```
<header>
    <div id="inner-border">
            <div id="header-wrapper">
                <a href="index.php" alt="Bryuvers Majas Lapa" id="logo"></a>
                <div id="social-share">
                    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
                    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_5"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4db8643a1c09a1ff"></script>
                    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

#### CSS

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    background: #120c09;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #100b07;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #100b07;
}

#inner-border {
    width: 100%;
    height: 103px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    border-top: 1px dashed #291a10;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #291a10;
}

#header-wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    height: 103px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
    height: 230px;
    width: 205px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    margin: -57px 0 0 0;
    background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat;

    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

#logo:hover {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#logo:active {
    margin: -55px 0 0 0;
}

#social-share {
    width: 280px;
    float: right;
    margin: -47px 0 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    opacity: 0.2;

    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s;
    -o-transition: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

#social-share:hover {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

---

**This is correct look:**

[image]

**This is inncorrect look (ie7, 6)**

[image]

Ignore css3 related stuff, the problem is that in ie 7,6 everything is squeezed to the top and search bar appears in the middle instead of on the right.

Comment: What exactly is the "correct" look?

Comment: Well, if you view it in Chrome, Mozilla or IE9 you can see how it should look ;) But it looks wrong in ie 6,7 the header is "squeezed" to the top

Comment: Firefox and Opera differ in output.

Comment: Might be because <header> is an HTML5 tag... which isn't supported in IE7. If you want it to work all round use divs

Comment: @Pluckerpluck he's got html5shim on the page, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of what you're seeing in IE6 will help identify what the correct vs incorrect looks are.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup - have a look at my comment about `hasLayout`.  This is most likely not a z-index or float issue.  Though that could be part of your problem, the disappearing `<div>` is probably caused by the `hasLayout` IE7 bug (which relates to `position: absolute` elements being adjacent to `position: relative` ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top nav is breaking up in IE7 because it is not properly defined what goes where and how. First, your logo is sort of "floating" inside of your document, since it is positioned absolutely with no point of reference in its container, so lets start by fixing that;

Add `position:relative` to your `#header-wrapper` CSS rule so we can properly contain your logo within its boundaries:

```
#header-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
```

Next, we have to rearrange your logo to properly sit in the middle of your `#header-wrapper` div. Previously you were using `margin: -57px auto 0 auto;` to align your logo but since you are already absolutely positioning it you don't really need margin at all (a miracle it was even working at all), so let's do some mathematics to absolutely position your logo in the middle of your header wrapper div:

First, we eliminate that margin declaration and replace it with the following:

```
#logo {
    left: 50%;
    top:-57px;
    margin-left: -102.5px;
}
```

Now, what did we do here? First we pushed your logo 50% from the left and then pushed it back with a negative margin by -102.5 pixels. Why did we do this? Because the `left` declaration pushes your element with width added to the calculation, so the push actually means "50% to the left + width of your element", so, we use the negative margin to compensate for the width, `50% - width/2`. [Here](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/) is a better explanation of the process.

After the two changes I listed are complete, you will find that the logo sits behind your slideshow area, this is due to the [ie7 z-index bug](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) and the fix is actually very simple:

```
header {
    position:relative;
    z-index:999; /* ie7 z-index bug fix */
}
```

We fix it by defining your header section as `position:relative` and give it a higher `z-index` than your slideshow area, this way your logo will be over your slideshow.

Now to fix your search bar from positioning itself to the left instead of the right we have to define your `#social-share` section as `position:absolute` and then push it to the right by using `right:0`, why? Because IE7 is positioning your search bar right next to the `#social-share` who is being pushed to the top by using a negative margin, and thus is not being removed from the stream as expected (was surprised it actually worked in modern browsers). So, define your `#social-share` section as absolute and the problem is solved:

```
#social-share {
   position:absolute;
   right:0;
}
```

And the final fix is a conditional class that we're going to use to target your `#_atssh` `<div>` tag to position it relatively to your document. IE7 is not taking it into account because it is absolutely positioned and so that long space is removed.

We can take advantage of your conditional classes added to your `<html>` tag by the boilerplate and target IE7 alone with a fix:

```
.ie7 #_atssh {
    position:relative;
}
```

Note: There is probably a billion typos and grammar errors, I wrote it during lunch so I'll comeback to this in the future and fix them.

Comment: Jesus, that's an awesome explanation! And I realized I have lots of revision to do now... Thank you very much ! I'll give you the bounty as soon as stackoverflow alows me ;)

Comment: The only thing that I don't understand is that #_atassh thing, could you please explain what it is?

Comment: @IlyaKnaup The `#_atssh` div is a container for your addthis plugin that is added to load certain scripts from an iframe and it is breaking because though its visibility is set to hidden it is still positioned absolutely, so ie7 is simply placing it "behind" your other elements and disregarding the fact that there is content in that space. My guess, of course, IE is funny like that sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html):

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

add this to the element that contains your floated element

Answer (score 1):

Based off what I can see (sorry, no IE6 or 7 available), you might be able to fix this by using `position` and `top` instead of using the negative margins like this:

1. Remove the `margin: -57px 0 0 0;` from `#logo` to be `top: 0px;`.  Since you're already using `position: absolute;`, this should place the logo at the top edge of the screen for you.
2. Remove the `margin: -47px 0 0 0;` from `#social-share` and instead add `position: relative; top: -47px;`

Including the proper `clear` or "clearfix" mentioned by JKirchartz may also be required.

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS property `zoom: 1` to `<div id="social-share">`, `header-wrapper`, or `inner-border`.

I like how quirks mode explains the issue of `hasLayout` which is an IE6 & IE7 specific problem: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html.